PyQt6 のQPushButtonがマウスオーバーで透過するのを無効化したい
概要
PyQt のQPushButtonがマウスオーバー、マウス押下で透過するのを無効化したい。
【バージョン】
Windows 11
python: 3.11.1
PyQt: 6.7.1
問題の詳細
QPushButtonにマウスオーバーすると、QPushButtonが白の半透明になる。
同様に、マウスクリックでも半透明化する。
現在検討しているGUIにおいては、
背景(QMainWindow)は白で、QPushButtonは濃い色に白文字なので、
ボタンが白の半透明になると、文字が見えにくくなる。
加えて、ボタン押下後に色を変えるようにしているが、
マウスホバーしている限り色が白の半透明なので、
色の変化が分からない、という問題もある。
QPushButtonであればなんでも、同様の事象が発生する。
(文字の有無、アイコンや画像の有無によらず)
マウスオーバー/クリックしてもボタンの色が変化しないようにしたい。
ただし、マウスクリックのイベントは取得する必要がある。
試したこと
その１
Attributeの設定。
クリックまで無効化されるのでNG
button = QPushButton()
button.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)

その２
マウスホバー時の色がColorRoleのどこかにあるかと思ったが、
どれでもないらしい。
color = QColor(255, 0, 0)
p =　button.palette()
p.setColor(QPalette.ColorRole.Base, color)
p.setColor(QPalette.ColorRole.Accent, color)
p.setColor(QPalette.ColorRole.Button, color)
p.setColor(QPalette.ColorRole.Window, color)
p.setColor(QPalette.ColorRole.AlternateBase, color)
button.setPalette(p)

その３
QPushButtonのeventを上書きしたら、
マウスホバー時に色が変わるという挙動は無効化できた。
ただ、マウスボタン押下中は半透明になるので、
根本的に「マウス操作をトリガにしてボタンが半透明になる」
挙動を無効化できているわけではないようだ。
class StockBtn(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text=None):
        super().__init__(text=text)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, a0: QMouseEvent | None) -> None:
        return a0.ignore()

button = StockBtn()

その４
フォーカスをclearFocus()によって消すことで
クリック時の透明化を無効化できないか確認した結果、無効化できなかった。
下記イベント関数内ではbutton.hasFocus()はTrueとなるので、
フォーカスは持っているようだ。
clearFocus()をしても、イベントを正常に返しているので、
その結果としてまたフォーカスを持ってしまうのか？
# その３のStockBtnクラス内に追加
    def mousePressEvent(self, e: QMouseEvent | None) -> None:
        self.clearFocus()
        return super().mousePressEvent(e)

ここが知りたい

半透明になるのが、何が原因で生じているのかを知りたい。
マウスホバー中のイベントを無視することで半透明化を無効化できたが、
何が原因で半透明になっているのかが分かっていない。
半透明化を無効化する方法を知りたい
今後、マウスホバー中のイベントを無視したくないことがあるかもしれないので、
mouseMoveEventをignoreで返さなくても、
半透明化を無効化する方法があればそれを知りたい。

ちなみに
これはサンプルプログラムです。
(白半透明になります)
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        btn = QPushButton('ぼたん')
        self.setCentralWidget(btn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.showMaximized()    
    sys.exit(app.exec())

よろしくお願いします。

Python3.11からPython3.12にバージョナップしたところ、半透明化しなくなりました。
QPushButtonを継承したクラスを定義してイベントをオーバーライドせずとも、期待通りの動作をしています。
Python3.11にインストールしていた何かのモジュールと相互作用でそのような動作になっていたのか、Python3.11との相性が悪かったのか、原因は分かりませんが、
インストール済みの他のモジュールと何か相互作用があったのか、Python3.11との相性が悪かっただけなのか分かりませんが、とりあえず解決してしまいました。

Qtはあまり詳しくはないのですが、そのような見栄えはスタイルシートで調整するのではないでしょうか。

Qt Style Sheets Examples
Qtのボタンの色変更やカスタマイズのやり方

Pythonじゃありませんが、メソッド名やスタイルシートは同じだと思うので、参考にして試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

コメントありがとうございます。
別件で不都合があったためPython3.11から3.12にアップグレードしたところ、半透明化の事象が全く発生しなくなりました (Python3.11は削除)。
スタイルシートによる見た目の変更は知っていましたが、「スタイルシートによる変更」と「setPalette等による変更」はどちらか一方しか取れない(一方を適用するともう一方の変更が無効化される)、という仕様上、手を出していませんでした。
そのため、katsuko様の回答でこの問題が改善するか否かは、検証できない状態です。
折角回答いただきましたが、このようなかたちでクローズとさせていただきます。
